# Grid view binding with different row values

Tags: c#, gridview

i have 3 tables A ,B and C
A has the primary key A_no used in both table B and C 
B and C are irrespective to each other .
combining these 3 tables , want to bind in grid view c#

[image]

how to avoid repetition of B column values in grid view

Comment: Have you considered writing a stored proc ? 
Write your logic there and call it.

Comment: too broad question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such logic directly integrated into the gridview.

You can either retrieve them directly by adjusting your query or EF logic or sort them yourself before binding the datasource (creating a new data structure class) or subscribe to the databound event of the gridview and implement the logic there.